# Calculate $\phi \langle \nabla H , \nabla \phi \rangle$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $H$ be the mean curvature of a hypersurface $\Sigma \subset M$ and $\phi \in C^\infty(\Sigma)$.

I want to calculate $\phi \langle \nabla H , \nabla \phi \rangle$.

Here I have two options:

$$\phi \langle \nabla H , \nabla \phi \rangle = 0 \tag{1}$$

and

$$\phi \langle \nabla H , \nabla \phi \rangle = - H \langle \nabla \phi , \nabla \phi \rangle = - H |\nabla \phi|^2 = H \phi \Delta \phi \tag{2}$$

since $H = const.$

**Question:**

Which one is correct?

Comment: It is not clear how you go from $\phi \langle \nabla H, \nabla  \phi\rangle$ to $H\langle \nabla \phi, \nabla \phi\rangle$....

Comment: @JohnMa Well, I am just guessing it from [equation (2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832174/jacobi-operator-of-a-hypersurface-sigma) that there exists $2H \phi \Delta \phi$ which is I think it comes from some terms in line 2 equation (1): $\phi \langle \nabla H,\nabla \phi⟩ − H \langle \nabla \phi, \nabla \phi \rangle = 2 H \phi \Delta \phi$ where $\psi = \phi$, but it's probably wrong then.

Comment: Well I meant $\phi \langle \nabla H, \nabla \phi \rangle = - H \langle \nabla \phi , \nabla \phi \rangle = H \phi \Delta \phi$.